# Теоретический вопрос о "Copy On Write"

Tags: ос, память, ассемблер, linux

Доброго времени суток.

После вызова `fork()` мы получаем два процесса с абсолютно идентичными адресными пространствами. Давным-давно в BSD система реально выделяла нужное количество новой памяти и копировала туда данные процесса-родителя во время вызова `fork()`. Сейчас есть технология копирования при изменении. Мне вот что интересно:

1. Что именно копируется при изменении? Допустим мы вызвали функцию в дочернем процессе, значит как минимум записали кое-что в стек. Ядро скопирует одну измененную страницу, весь сегмент стека, все сегменты приложения или еще что-то?
2. Как происходит копирование? Неужели по-байтово? Или процессор может копировать например целую страницу за 1 инструкцию? Я о таком никогда не слышал...

Comment: 1. Все страницы, где изменится хоть байт. 2. Я про процессоры, которые копируют страницу за одну инструкцию ни разу не слыхал (А страницы сейчас большие).

Comment: Для моделирования такой команды (пересылка блока) в x86 можно использовать например REP MOVS информация взята [отсюда](http://www.club155.ru/x86cmd/MOVS?pid=1)

В системе команд майнфреймов IBM тоже есть команда пересылки блока память-память.

Comment: Да уж. Однако

Comment: Вроде как для копирования используются инструкции MMX. Пока копаю в этом направлении :)

Answer (score 3):

Копируется страница. Копирование исполняет тот же код, что и обычное копирование аргументов из пространства пользователя и по факту не отличается от быстрых вариантов реализации `memcpy`. Так для `amd64` существует три реализации (вызываются из обработчика страничного прерывания, фактически [отсюда](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.4/source/mm/memory.c#L2494)):

- Базовая, [copy_user_generic_unrolled](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.4/source/arch/x86/lib/copy_user_64.S#L32) общий алгоритм: копирование происходит через четыре 64-битных регистра по 64 байта за итерацию цикла.
- Базовая на основе строковых инструкций, [copy_user_generic_string](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.4/source/arch/x86/lib/copy_user_64.S#L136), с использованием [rep](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_203.html); [movsq](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_279.html). По факту копирование целой страницы происходит в течение выполнения одной микрокоманды — movsq. Алгоритм доступен на системах предоставляющих расширение `rep_good` (см. `flags` в `/proc/cpuinfo`).
- Быстрая на основе строковых инструкций, [copy_user_enhanced_fast_string](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.4/source/arch/x86/lib/copy_user_64.S#L176), аналогично предыдущей, но использует `rep; movsb` на системах, с поддержкой расширения `erms` (см. `flags` в `/proc/cpuinfo`) — особо быстрой системой реализации копирования.

Answer (score 1):

Копируется страница целиком. Как именно - скорее всего именно побайтово. Надо смотреть исходники ядра.

Comment: Скорее всего машинными словами: то есть по 4 или по 8 байт.