# Что происходит с памятью при вызове exec() на уровне ядра?

Tags: linux, процесс

Вопрос теоретический. `fork()` делает копию процесса. Известно, что родительский процесс имеет **собственное адресное пространство**. Дочерний процесс, фактически, до какого-то момента может работать с адресным пространством своего родителя. Этот момент - запись в адресное пространство. Таким образом дочерний процесс в режиме **"только чтение"** может в полной мере руководствоваться родительским адресным пространством. Если производится запись, то адресное пространство **копируется** (copy-on-write [COW]). Возникает несколько вопросов:

1. Что будет со скопированным адресным пространством, если будет вызван **exec()**?
2. Если после **fork()** вызвать **exec()**, то новый исполняемый код создает *свое* собственное адресное пространство?
3. Что будет с таблицей страниц дочернего процесса после вызова **exec()**?

Comment: связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816388/178576 // там в ответах и комментариях есть ещё дополнительные ссылки.

Comment: Дочерний процесс работает со своим адресным пространством, которое создается в fork. При его создании делают новые таблицы MMU (копируя родительские, кроме стека). Виртуальных адреса ссылаются на те же физические страницы, что и в таблице родителя. Для writable  страниц выставляются атрибуты, которые при записи приводят к копированию (и выделению новой физической) страницы. При выполнении exec адресное пространство (по крайней мере частично) перестраивается.

Comment: Позволил себе подправить заголовок, т.к. вопрос всё же про `exec ()`, а не про `fork()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Рассматривать что происходит с памятью при вызове `exec()` в отрыве от остальной подсистемой управления пямятью — неполноценно и описать этот процесс можно только в общих словах. А по всей данной подсистеме можно написать целую книгу (и несколько уже написаны), но я всё же попытаюсь выделить основные моменты.

### Немного о структурах связанных с управлением памятью процесса

Кратко опишу назначение основных структур связанных с управлением памятью процесса.

Структуры связанные с управлением виртуальным АП.

- [`task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/include/linux/sched.h#L524) — дескриптор процесса
- [`mm_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L350) — адресное пространство процесса
- [`vm_area_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L274) — отдельный сегмент памяти процесса со своим набором атрибутов (rwx), можно думать о нём как о неком регионе отображённом в память `mmap ()`'ом: он может быть и частью файла (исполняемого или обычного) и простым анонимным участком памяти. Список можно посмотреть, например в `/proc/<pid>/maps`.

Структуры связанные с трансляцией адресов и физической памятью:

- `pgd_t` и `pmd_t` (а также `p4d` и `pud`) — системно-зависимые типы для записей в *глобальной директории страниц* (*Page Global Directory*) и *промежуточной директории страниц* (*Page Middle Directory*), если таковая есть (на простом x86 таковой нет). `p4d` и `pud` — это дополнительные типы в новых ядрах для пятиуровневой и четырёхуровневой адресации.
- `pte_t` — системно-зависимый тип Записи в таблице страниц (`Page Table Entries`). На x86 это, как и pgd_t 32-битный тип [с аналогичным названием](https://studfiles.net/preview/2703664/page:5/).
- [`struct page`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L76) — системно-независимая структура представляющая страницу физической памяти. Все они постоянно хранятся в памяти в массиве `mem_map`.

Если кратко, то эти структуры взаимосвязаны следующим образом:

- `task_struct.mm` ссылается на `mm_struct`, связанный с процессом. На один `mm_struct` может ссылаться несколько `task_struct` (так в частности реализованы потоки)
- `mm_struct.mmap` в свою очередь ссылается на двусвязный список `vm_area_struct`, связанных с процессом.
- `mm_struct.pgd` хранит адрес глобальной директории страниц `pgd_t` связанной с процессом. На x86 он фактически [загружается](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/arch/x86/mm/tlb.c#L304) в [CR3](https://studfiles.net/preview/2703664/page:5/) при смене контекста.
- `vm_area_struct.mm` — указатель на `mm_struct` к которому принадлежит данный сегмент.
- `vm_area_struct.next` и `vm_area_struct.prev` — указатели на предыдущий и следующий элемент в двусвязном списке.
- Для `pte_t` и `pgd_t` можно получить соответствующую структуру `struct page` с помощью макросов и `pte_page()` и `pgd_page()` соответственно.

### Немного о том, как работает COW

При создании нового процесса `fork ()`'ом [цикл](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/kernel/fork.c#L436) проходится по всем связанным с ним `vm_area_struct` и [помечает](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/mm/memory.c#L1025) все доступные на запись страницы (`pte_t`), доступными только на чтение. А в соответствующей `struct page` [увеличивается](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/mm/memory.c#L1040) счётчик ссылок на страницу.

Когда процесс пытается записать в такую страницу, происходит прерывание, далее [обработчик](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L1488) (спустившись на несколько функций по стеку вызовов) [определяет](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.4/source/mm/memory.c#L3993), что хотя прерывание произошло на странице на которой запрещена запись (согласно `pte_t`), эта страница относится к сегменту, в котором она разрешена (согласно vm_area_struct). Таким образом определяется, что это одна из COW-страниц и происходит [копирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/80435/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BE-copy-on-write/819477#819477). После чего [уменьшается](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.4/source/mm/memory.c#L2561) счётчик ссылок исходной страницы (в `struct page`) и, если он достиг нуля, снова разрешается запись в неё.

### Что происходит с адресным пространством при `execve()`

Сначала `exec()` [создаёт](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/fs/exec.c#L1771) новое АП (`mm_struct`) частично его инициализирует (например [создаёт стек](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/fs/exec.c#L293)), А потом [пробует](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/fs/exec.c#L1638) подсунуть файл поочерёдно каждому из модулей поддержки форматов (например [ELF](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L685)) пока один из них не сможет его загрузить. Модуль в свою очередь сначала проводит частичную проверку формата и также частичную инициализацию АП, а затем, когда убедится, что формат выбран правильно и скорей всего удастся загрузить данный файл, [происходит](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L864) [подмена](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/fs/exec.c#L1248) старого АП новым и последующая [подчистка](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/fs/exec.c#L1034) старого. В частности она включает:

- [Уменьшение](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/kernel/fork.c#L980) количества пользователей АП (`mm_struct.users`), если оно достигло нуля, то:

  - [В цикле](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/mm/memory.c#L1579) обходятся все `vm_area_struct` и для каждой происходит рекурсивная итерация по каталогу страниц в результате счётчики ссылок всех ассоциированных страниц (`struct page`) [уменьшаются](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/mm/memory.c#L1337) аналогично тому как это было описано для COW.
  - После этого [в другом цикле](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/mm/mmap.c#L3046) обходятся все `vm_area_struct` и записываются несохранённые данные из грязных страниц `mmap`-файлов.
  - [Уменьшается](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/include/linux/sched/mm.h#L49) количество ссылок на АП (`mm_struct.count`) и если оно достигло нуля (кроме процессов структура может использоваться другими подсистемами ядра), то она полностью [удаляется](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/kernel/fork.c#L604).

В случае успешного завершения модуль формата продолжит инициализацию АП, а затем произойдёт передача управления процессу.

Стоит заметить, что операция подмены АП(вызов [`flush_old_exec()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/fs/exec.c#L1248)) — это точка невозвращения, т.е. после оной `exec ()` уже не сможет вернуть одну из [документированных](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=2&russian=&topic=execve#lbAF) ошибок; и в случае сбоя весь процесс будет аварийно завершён по сигналу, например, [`SIGSEGV`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.5/source/fs/exec.c#L1645).

### Односложные ответы на конкретные вопросы

> 1. Что будет со скопированным адресным пространством, если будет вызван **exec()**?

Оно будет замещено другим, созданным `exec ()`.

> 2. Если после **fork()** вызвать **exec()**, то новый исполняемый код создает *свое* собственное адресное пространство?

Да.

> 3. Что будет с таблицей страниц дочернего процесса после вызова **exec()**?

Она также будет замещена новой. Страницы не используемые другими будут добавлены в список свободных.

### Дальнейшее чтение:

[Understanding The Linux Virtual Memory Manager](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/index.html) — Книга описывает довольно старое ядро, но отличия в основном косметические, а основные принципы не изменились.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой раскрытый ответ