# Безопасность данных на стаке при вызове функций exec

Tags: c, безопасность, exec, стек

Мучает такой вопрос - после вызова execve (или любой из exec*) новая программа может прочитать данные, хранящиеся на стаке в предыдещей программе в момент вызова?
В манах указано, что новый процес замещает текущий, следует ли это понимать, что всё содержимое стака перейдёт под контроль новому процессу? Если да, то достаточно ли будет занулить все критичные переменные с помощью memset или есть другие более правильные решения?

Comment: Я думаю, (по крайней мере в `Linux avp-desktop 5.4.0-99-generic #112~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 3 14:09:57 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`) вы можете не опасаться. Судя по экспериментам с чтением стека (в т.ч. подсчетом ненулевых байт), содержимое стека "родителя" (того, кто вызывает execl) недоступно "потомку", который читает почти полностью обнуленный свой стек. Независимо от того в тех же или разных виртуальных адресах размещались их стеки

Comment: memset не обязан занулять неиспользуемые данные.

Comment: `достаточно ли будет занулить все критичные переменные с помощью memset` — [Безопасная очистка приватных данных](https://habr.com/ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/281072/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, не стоит беспокоиться, `execve()` создаёт полностью новое адресное пространство и в том числе новый стек. Ни какие посторонние данные из старого процесса в новый не «утекают», а необходимые данные вроде аргументов или переменных среды копируются. Ничего вручную затирать не обязательно.

Подробно о том как работает `execve()` на примере linux я уже писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819348/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5-exec-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0/820486#820486).